How to redirect after merge
I'm trying to get the exit code of an ls command with no other output. To do this I'm using
ls /foo/bar/rak/zif/poo 2>&1 > /dev/null; echo $?

But when I do this, I get a ls: cannot access /foo/bar/rak/zif/poo: No such file or directory message. Why is that stderr still appearing? And aside for redirecting each stream to /dev/null separately,is there a way to get this to work?
